# Create combination sql table

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a sql table in data base in VS that has room and userid column, but the sql will only accept your input if the userid exists in users table and room exists in rooms tables

Allows:

```
Users table:
 Userid
1
2
3
```

RoomUsers table:

```
Room ----- User

1          1
2.         1
1.         2
1.         3
2.         3
```

Won't allow:

```
Users table:
 Userid
1
2
```

RoomUsers table:

```
Room ----- User

1          4
```

Normal foreign key wont work because it only allows one of each index and not multiple, how can I allow what I need to occur,to happen?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post your table structures and data examples as well.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking and why normal foreign key wouldn't work. People in the world have been doing such many-to-many relations using a bridge table (like your userId, roomId - RoomUser) since many many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This would be a mess in comments)
Probably we are having an XY problem here. The thing you describe is simply solved with a foreign key. ie:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ad VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE rooms (id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ad VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE room_user
  (
    RoomId INT NOT NULL
  , UserId INT NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT PK_roomuser
      PRIMARY KEY(RoomId, UserId)
  , CONSTRAINT fk_room
      FOREIGN KEY(RoomId)
      REFERENCES dbo.rooms(id)
  , CONSTRAINT fk_user
      FOREIGN KEY(UserId)
      REFERENCES dbo.users(id)
  );

INSERT INTO dbo.users(ad)
OUTPUT
  Inserted.id, Inserted.ad
VALUES('RayBoy')
    , ('John')
    , ('Frank');

INSERT INTO dbo.rooms(ad)
OUTPUT
  Inserted.id, Inserted.ad
VALUES('Room1')
    , ('Room2')
    , ('Room3');

INSERT INTO dbo.room_user(RoomId, UserId)VALUES(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3);

-- won't allow
INSERT INTO dbo.room_user(RoomId, UserId)VALUES(999, 888);
```

Comment: Nice touch with the the OUTPUT, makes it very clear to see what is happening and what id:s are available.

Comment: Thx, It worked, but I don't understand why it works. Why doesn't it allow me when I have one foreign key to have duplicates but here it does, does the act of having more then one primary key change something? or is the act of more then on foreign key what allows it?

Comment: @Raaaayboy123, sorry I don't understand your question. By duplicate do you mean values like 1, 2 and 1, 3? If so then yes, both fields are part of the primary key and thus to be a duplicate both of them should be duplicated.